# Is there an alternative to accomplish what Assert does and have the test fully execute when it fails without using a Try Catch?

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I am writing tests for UI and am using assert statements to check if an element is present with string for the message when the assert fails. I would like the test to continue to check for other elements even if it fails to find an element. I would also like to have the useful message that shows when the asserts fails to be there at the end of the test.

```
Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//a/img[@src='/Img1.png']")), "Img1 not present");
Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//a/img[@src='/Img2.png']")), "Img2 not present");
Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//a/img[@src='/Img3.png']")), "Img3 not present");
```

Is there an alternative to using assert statements or having the assert statement in a try catch for the test to continue?

Comment: that question asks why "mstest" assert try catch is not functioning correctly. What I want to know is: is there an alternative to doing an assert or using a try catch and still be able to assert and have an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You could hold the error message and then check at the end. The below is horrible code and you would want to tidy it up, but it gives an idea of what you could do.

```
[Test]
public void All_images_are_present()
{
    string message = string.Empty;

    message = AssertImage("Img1");
    message += AssertImage("Img2");
    message += AssertImage("Img3");
    ... etc ...

    Assert.That(message, Is.Empty, message);
}

private static string AssertImage(string imageName)
{
    string imagePath = string.Format(@"//a/img[@src='/{0}.png']", imageName);

    if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//a/img[@src='/Img1.png']")))
        return string.Empty;

    return string.Format("{0} not present;");    
}
```

However, it might be better to have three different tests and check each image in each one. The tests should ideally check one piece of functionality each.

Comment: I am concern about multiplying lines of codes with solutions like this because all my tests would be checking dozens of elements.

Comment: @Anthony Don. Have edited to make it easier to check more elements without loads of extra lines of code as per your comment.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts Andy but I should have been clearer. I am doing UI tests and a test would be to go to login page. Then check if title, company logo, label for name input, label for password is present. Then login and check if the "logout" text is present to make sure login was successful. So it would not work the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, we call that an "[if statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_statement#If.E2.80.93then.28.E2.80.93else.29)".  `Assert.IfTrue(condition, message)` is merely a shorthand form for:

```
if (condition) then
    print message
    abort_execution
end-if
```

Comment: That is an interesting break down. I am still a beginner at programming so I thought there were some alternative I didn't know about that leaves out the "abort_execution" part. Something like Verify.IfTrue(condition, message).

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your solution would be using parametrized tests. In NUnit, you can make such by using `[TestCase]` attribute.

Following example is rewritten to parametrized tests:

```
[TestCase("//a/img[@src='/Img1.png']")]
[TestCase("//a/img[@src='/Img2.png']")]
[TestCase("//a/img[@src='/Img3.png']")]
public void ElementIsPresent(string xpath)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.XPath(xpath)));
}
```

Now, you are able to distinguish two types of red tests: ones in which expectations differs (here: if false is returned instead of true) and those which throws an exception in the way.

There is also another problem with your approach. As Andy Nichols mentioned, you are testing more than one logical assert in one test. Unit test should have no more than one logical assert per test. Having parametrized tests as per above guarantee you are testing one logical assert in one test.